# ReferenceError: "bot" is not defined (Eris) - in my commands

Tags: node.js, discord, bots, referenceerror, eris

I am in the process of creating a Discord bot, and I have gotten pretty far. However, I keep getting this error when I try to connect my bot:

> ReferenceError: bot is not defined

My main file's code is [here](https://pastebin.com/S1Gc3id5). I have defined the constant variable `bot` to require the Eris library.

However, when I try to run the code, my command code throws the error mentioned above. I have tried to use multiple versions of `module.exports` but nothing seems to work. My command's code is located [here](https://pastebin.com/0bwHHUHu).

Comment: In the future, please include all relevant code in your post and [**don't** just include a link to a code hosting site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94027/316262). Your post should stand alone from any other resource; [consider what would happen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) if that site went down in the future!

Answer (score 0):

The `bot` constant will only exist in the main file, so you'll need a way to pass it over to the commands file. You could export a function from the commands file with `bot` as a parameter

```
const Permissions = require('eris').Constants.Permissions;

module.exports = function(bot){
    // paste in the rest of the commands code
};
```

And then run the function in the main file

```
require('../src/commands/loader')(bot);
```